# Prevent continued loading of only current file without interrupting loading of parent file?

Tags: php

Looking at the following structure:

groups.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('header.php');
if($_SESSION['admin'])
{ include('groups_admin.php'); }

... html ...

?>
```

groups_admin.php

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['admin'])
{ die(); }
... html ...
?>
```

inside of groups_admin.php - performing the die(); causes the rest of the page (including groups.php) to stop loading.

without wrapping all of groups_admin.php is a big if statement and reversing it; is there anyway to tell PHP to just stop loading that specific PHP file while inside of that file?

Comment: If you only ever include `groups_admin.php` in this way, the `if(!$_SESSION['admin'])` condition will never resolve `true`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Apologies; I've added session_start(); to my sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a return in the include eg:

```
<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['admin']))
{ return false; }
... html ...
?>
```

A lot of people don't know you can return a value from an included file.

Just for completion of this answer. You have a couple of other, less elegant (and not recommended) options.

- You throw an exception and catch it outside of the include
- Wrap it in an if block

Comment: Thank you; I know about return in functions but it didn't occur to me that I could use it in an include. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is suboptimal compared to the `return` solution, I just can't help it.

Guess what: **php supports [goto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)**!

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['admin'])
{ goto endoffile; }
... html ...
endoffile:
?>
```

I just found out myself and it zapped me back in time, to my GWBASIC years... *(sigh!)*